# Printing array elements as difference between the max value of the array

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, max

I wrote a program to get an array which will return an array with elements as difference between max value and remaining elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void behind(int *, int);

int main(void) {
    int array[10];
    int N, i;
    
    scanf("%d", &N);
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    behind(array, N);
    for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void behind(int *ptr,int size) /* Write your function behind() here: */
{
    int i,max=0;
    for(i=1;i<size;i++){
        if(ptr[i-1]>=ptr[i])
        max=ptr[i-1];
        else
        max = ptr[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<size;i++);
    ptr[i]=max-ptr[i];
    
}
```

why my program always return the same array that I got as input?

Comment: `for(i=0;i<size;i++);` is equivalent to `i = size;` (if `size` is positive). Then only `ptr[size]` will be updated in the function `behind`. Note that also how to obtain the maximum value is wrong.

Comment: @noobcoder There is a semicolon after this for loop for(i=0;i<size;i++); Also you are determining the maximum value incorrectly.

Comment: You have a typo: an extra `;` at the end of the `for` line.

Comment: You set `max = INT_MIN;` to begin. (`#include <limits.h>`) Then loop `for (int i = 0; i < n) { if (ptr[i] > max) max = ptr[i] }`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  at each loop execution my max value will be max of two consecutive elements. I'm confused why this is wrong. I getting correct value after removing the semicolon in the for loop.

Comment: @noobcoder Consider for example an array { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 }. Using this array you will get that the maximum value is 2 will not you?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yeah..I'm wrong.. Thanks